# How to calculate the maximum value for a border-radius without using percentage?

Tags: css

CSS3 uses the `border-radius` attribute to set rounded corners in elements. The values, normally, are set in *px*, and the lowest value allowed is *0px*. The visual result are variable, according to the dimensions of the element with this attribute. For example, an element with dimensions *100px X 100px* with `border-radius: 20px;`, will not get totally rounded(circle), otherwise, an element with *dimensions 10px X 10px* will be. There are no limit to the maximum value allowed.

The question is: how to calculate the **maximum value**, according to the element size, to make it 100% rounded?

[Fiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/Jp5L3/)

**EDIT : How to calculate the value in pixels (px)?**

Comment: the question should be `minimum value`, the maximum value would be a maximal integer value followed by `%`, which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Not that are possible to set a higher value if you only are changing one corner. Example: `border-radius:100% 0;` is visually different of `border-radius:50% 0;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not use a percent?

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

Just make sure whatever you're applying it to is square.

Comment: exactly. the 50% will be applyed for each corner

Answer (score 13):

The right way should be

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius) states you can use a percentage value here, and it should be derived from the corresponding dimensions of the  `border-box` of the element.

The [image from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/corner.png) illustrates why `50%` is the right value if you need a circle:

[image]

If your element is not square (height != width), you could still use it to get a nice ellipse.

Comment: No. If you set 80%, it will be totally rounded too. Try is in the link i posted.

Comment: Well, 10000000%  would make it totally rounded in theory also... The maximum value is infinity or whatever the largest value CSS can support.

Comment: `border-radius: 50%` [will also give you an ellipse](http://jsfiddle.net/tse6t/).

Comment: @Joseph Silber due it was set to an rectangule, not an square.

Comment: i think your second example should have been `border-radius: 50%/50%`, but that would be unnecessary as @JosephSilber pointed out.