# border radius rounded corner with css only

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image]

Can I achieve this with css only?

[50% does not work on rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524875/how-to-calculate-the-maximum-value-for-a-border-radius-without-using-percentage)

*1 more thing: no fixed height.*

Comment: You can set a `min-height` to the element if you don't need to fix the height.

Comment: This is how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/5sanz08e/ and don't forget the vendor prefixes.

Comment: @lharby It fails when the content of the box is large: http://jsfiddle.net/5sanz08e/2/ — Besides, nowadays using vendor prefixes is not necessary for `border-radius`.

Comment: This related question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048234/css-make-responsive-oval-block althought it is for a fluid with rather than fluid height.

Comment: Is it specified in the question that there will be text content inside the div?

Comment: @web-tiki I guess the answer is close to 'not possible'. ("For this you will need a "fixed" height otherwise, you'll need to calculate this with jquery")

Comment: @lharby Ya, text inside.

Comment: @Timeless there is a way to achieve this with fluid height using a high px value for border radius as one of the answers here points out. This is also explained in one of the answers of the question I linked.

Comment: @web-tiki are you saying 50vw? seems it works

Comment: @Timeless I didn't say that but it seems to work like a hight px value.

Comment: @web-tiki currently my solution is just set as 999px. just curious about any elegant solution. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to set a fixed value for horizontal `border-radius` as follows:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px / 50%;
  
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #009EE0;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  Stuff goes <br>
  here... <br>
  & here... <br>
  Setting a fixed value of horizontal border-radius does the trick!
</div>
```

You may also want to use a different percentage value instead:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 12% / 50%;

  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #009EE0;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  Stuff goes <br>
  here... <br>
  & here... <br>
  Or set a different percentage value for horizontal border-radius
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
div{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:lightblue;
    border-radius:50px;
  border:2px solid black
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Edit: use `50vw` for making it responsive any height will be okay

```css
div{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background:orange;
    border-radius:50vw;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Can I achieve this on a rectangle without a fixed height.

Comment: @Timeless No fixed height??

Comment: @Timeless Do you have text in it?

Comment: @Timeless the css he posted is not wrong in the example there is a fixed height, but you could just as good use something as `height:auto;`. Since the question was about the rounded corners and all that awnsers that would be `border-radius:50px;`. For more information about it please take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp).

Comment: @Akshay wouldn't `height:auto;` work as well to size it to what ever height the contents need?

Comment: @maam27 Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/r9gca0LL/2/) i used `50px` but it doesn't give a nice effect so i used `50vw`

Comment: @Akshay both work I suppose but since OP said no fixed height the `height:auto;` may be something he could use, thats why I thought I'd ask. Personally im not really into making websites so it's more of a suggestion to the OP.

Comment: @maam27 You are right `height:auto` is the perfect way

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick for that

Just us a very large **`border-radius`** value!

e.g. `{border-radius:10000px;}`

Here is link to demo (Try changing width/height to see working) : [http://jsfiddle.net/890z699p/](http://jsfiddle.net/890z699p/1/)

```css
.rect {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: This will work, the problem is that your fiddle uses percentages for border-radius instead of a hight px value as you show in your answer. Also, please add the code of your example in the question itself.

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks for pointing out mistake! I didn't updated the jsFiddle :D, It is fine now!

Answer (score 0):

It works on me, below is my code snippet

```css
div {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #009EE0;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to double check your final result, the OP wants a rectangle with rounded corners, this code produces an oval.